# Rails joins doesn't return values from joined table

Tags: ruby-on-rails

It must be something pretty simple i'm doing wrong. i'm trying to join 3 tables together, where `group` contains a `location_id` which references a row in `location` and a `info_id` which does the same for `info`.

Here's my code:

```
@groups = Group.joins(
    'INNER JOIN location on location.id = "group".id', 
    'INNER JOIN info on info.id = "group".id'
)
```

This seems to work without errors, but all i'm getting back is the column from my `group` table. What am I doing wrong here?

P.S. my associations are `location` and `info` belong_to `group`. and group `has_one` of `location` and `info`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just add a select tag to select the desired columns.

```
Group.joins(:location, :info).select("location.*, info.*")
```

You may also add a where clause if needed.

```
Group.joins(:location, :info).select("location.*, info.*").where("locations.id = conditions.id")
```

Comment: I added a `.select` and nothing changed. No errors again but i'm still only getting a list of Groups without any info. I ran this
`res = Group.joins('INNER JOIN location on location.id = "group".id').select('"group".*', "location.*")`

Answer (score 2):

When you say that you have `location_id` and `info_id` in `groups` table, this means that you intend to have `belongs_to` association in `Group`.

Pre-requisite:
`Group` model should have:

```
belongs_to :location
belongs_to :info
```

`Location` and `Info` should have :

```
has_one :group
```

For your question, this is expected. In ActiveRecord, Relation will return the object of the invoker, in this case `Group`.

For your use case, I think you will need this approach to get the right join working:

Query:

```
@groups = Group.joins(:location, :info)
# "SELECT `groups`.* FROM `groups` INNER JOIN `locations` ON `locations`.`id` = `groups`.`location_id` INNER JOIN `infos` ON `infos`.`id` = `groups`.`info_id`"
```

After this, you can iterate on each group to get info and location as something like: `@groups.map { |group| [group.location, group.info] }`
This will give correct location and info.

Optimization: `[group.location, group.info]` will make queries again to get location and info. You can optimize this by changing the original query to include location and info data:

```
@groups = Group.joins(:location, :info).includes(:location, :info)
```

Answer (score 1):

In Rails / AR we have `includes` and `joins`.

You are using `joins`. As the SQL shows, it only selects `Group`. You use `joins` when you need `Group` results but also want to query through `Location` and `Info`.

If you would use all information, which I suspect is your case, like to display details in a table, you should also use `includes`.

```
# @groups = Groups.includes(:locations, :info) results an left outer join
@groups = Groups.joins(:locations, :info).includes(:locations, :info) # results inner join
```

Now when you do some thing like this it will not make additional db calls. But if you use `joins` it use multiple queries (N+1).

```
- @groups.each do |group|
  tr
    td = group.id
    td = group.location.lat
    td = group.info.description
```

Use the bullet gem to find if you have such N+1 queries to optimize your project.

If you Google `Rails includes vs joins` you will find more information on the topic.

Comment: Not really. The original intention of using INNER join is mostly to get those rows for which joined table's row exists. With INNER join, we can exclusively make sure that whatever `group` I'm getting back, it has an equivalent location and info. `includes` alone won't do that for you. `group.location`, `group.info` will very conveniently fail

Comment: @kiddorails: conveniently fail if...?

Comment: @kiddorails but i stand corrected, i actually though both were using inner joins. need to read up on the matter. So we need also include the stuff to make it an inner join.

Comment: Sure. Have a look at the queries when you run  `@groups = Groups.includes(:locations, :info)` .By no means, it does a join when including the associations(to resolve N+1). I never said `includes` is wrong. Just wanted to stress that comparing `joins` and `includes` doesn't make sense. they serve different purpose.

Comment: Generally in the projects I work on, the inner join is the best. The left outer join becomes handy when we want all of left. So seems the best way to get it done is like you show `joins(:table1, :table2..).includes(:table1, table2)`...

Answer (score 0):

If you used this:

```rb
  Group.joins(:location, :info).select("location.*, info.*").where("locations.id = 
  conditions.id")
```

and nothing changed

It is because the column names of the two tables are the same.